# Trace width for breaking out 100Ω differential microstrip from 0.5mm pitch BGA

Tags: differential, transmission-line, microwave, bga, displayport

**See bottom of post for the actual questions**

First, some context:

- I'm making a DisplayPort switch as a hobby project
- DisplayPort's high speed lines require 100Ω ± 10% differential impedance, which I'll be requesting impedance control from the fab
- Off-the-shelf DisplayPort switch ICs are only available in 0.5mm pitch BGA (e.g., [TI HD3SS214](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slas907b/slas907b.pdf))
- Ideally I want to support HBR3, which runs at 8.1Gbit/s (8b/10b encoded), or a fundamental frequency of 4.05GHz, so transmission line impedance matters
- I can use FR-4 (ε<sub>r</sub> = 4.2~4.4 @ 5GHz) or RO4350B (ε<sub>r</sub> = 3.66) dielectrics
- This is my first time working on a high speed design

So due to the 0.5mm pitch BGA limitation, the widest trace I can fit between the balls is 76.6µm (3.02mil). Fortunately, this *just* fits within the minimum trace width of 3mil on 1oz copper for the fab I've tentatively chosen ([WellPCB](https://www.wellpcb.com/capabilities.html)).

But such thin traces present a problem in achieving 100Ω differential impedance (on a differential microstrip). My fab's standard 1st-to-2nd layer dielectric thickness on FR-4 is 213µm (7628H). Using the minimum trace spacing of 76.2µm (3mil) with the 76.6µm width, this results in Z<sub>diff</sub> = 110~115Ω (according to [MMTL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mmtl/)), which is out of spec! Using the thinnest available RO4350B (168µm) is even worse with Z<sub>diff</sub> = 117Ω due to the much lower ε<sub>r</sub>.

While I can increase the trace width if I get around the balls with vias instead of routing between them (the bottom layer already contains *other* high speed traces), this would mean I would have to add an extra two layers to the PCB ($$$), and would be extra impedance mismatch.
Alternatively I can taper the traces to a larger width immediately after escaping the BGA, but this is annoying to do on my EDA software (KiCAD).

I could also try to ask the fab to use a custom FR-4 stackup, with a thinner upper layer, but I'm not sure how thin they can go.
I simulated the Z<sub>diff</sub> on thinner FR-4 (see below image), and it seems 100µm would be ideal.

[image: Simulated Z<sub>diff</sub>]

I also worry that being right on the minimum 3mil trace width and spacing would mean the fab wouldn't be able to perform their own impedance control, since I heard it's primarily done by adjusting the trace width (can't go wider or won't fit between BGA balls; can't go narrower or it goes below the minimum 3mil).

**Questions:**

- Should I be worried in using the minimum trace width and spacing of 3mil, when simulations show this results in a too high impedance? Will the fab be able to properly lower it?
- If not, how would you recommend I break out the differential pairs?
- Are my Z<sub>diff</sub> simulations with [MMTL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mmtl/) accurate at all? I haven't been able to cross-check with other EM simulators, while simple online calculators have been giving me even higher values.
- Have I made any stupid mistakes or incorrect assumptions? First time on a high speed design after all...

Comment: The problem you have is getting away from the chip. Once you escape the BGA, you can adjust the width/spacing to be within the 100 ohm tolerance, just remember to take into account the thinner traces when impedance/length matching.

Answer (score 1):

Neck-down traces are a common approach for this issue. If your PCB vendor can deal with the spacing and track width then this then it's a reasonable approach.

Otherwise I suggest using microvias to escape the traces to the bottom layer. Then you have more flexibility in trace width to achieve both Zo(diff) and Zo(single-ended), and the board will have better manufacturing yield.